# Boot .efi files from GRUB2

Tags: boot, grub2, android

I've bought a Sony VAIO with UEFI booting and came with Windows 8 preinstalled. I successfully installed Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 7 (triple-boot) and fixed the UEFI boot so GRUB2 is loading.

I was just wondering if I can boot `.efi` files from grub?

**Related problems:**

- I used Clover EFI to boot OS X 10.9 (which I installed to boot, can't boot it with GRUB2: AICPUPM KP) and because of it I couldn't boot to either Windows or Ubuntu.
- After that I installed Android 4.4 x86 and added its boot entry and I got KP related to `efivar` (or something like that), so I wanted to try Gummiboot.

**My question is:**

Can I boot `.efi` files such as `gummiboot.efi` and `cloverx64.efi` from `GRUB2` so I can preserve it for Windows and Ubuntu booting?

Comment: You might want to ask the Android 4.4 Kernel Panic related part of your question at [Unix & Linux S.E.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=x86+panic) since it doesn't seem to be related to Ubuntu.

Comment: In fact, a lot of people using Android 4.4 from android-x86.org got this problem when booting from GRUB 2 from a UEFI system, and the main developer said that we need to recompile the whole system from scratch and remove **CONFIG_EFI_VARS** from **kernel/arch/x86/configs/android-x86_defconfig**, and as I don't have a really fast internet I couldn't download the whole 10GB of source code! and I just wanted to boot Gummiboot from GRUB, the efivar error isn't that important, maybe someone will help us and upload his version of the kernel :)

Answer (score 6):

It's basically the same as booting `bootmgfw.efi` from Windows 8, but a bit simpler.

```
menuentry "Gummiboot" {
        insmod chain
        insmod search_fs_uuid
        search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root $UUID
        chainloader /EFI/boot/bootx64.efi
}
```

Just replace `$UUID` with the **UUID** of the filesystem where you have put Gummiboot or the efi-binary you want to boot (use `blkid` or `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/` to get the UUID). For FAT filesystems the UUID should look something similar to this: `00000-0000`

`insmod chain` and `insmod search_fs_uuid` may just be optional, I could remove them from the configuration during my quick tests and was still able to boot the binary.

Alternatively you could add `insmod ntfs` or `insmod ext2` if you have the binary on another **filesystem** like NTFS or EXT[234] (may require `insmod part_msdos` or `insmod part_gpt` if the filesystem is on a disk with a different **partition table** format).

`/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi` is my Gummiboot file in this example, as I have it as the default bootloader of my ESP.