# How to boot to efi USB stick from Grub command line

Tags: grub2, live-usb, grub-efi

I am trying to boot to an USB stick from Grub, and I have found a few sites that explain how to do it, but when I follow those instructions it does not seem to work. I think those guides may simply be outdated. I did find https://askubuntu.com/a/436735, but that one seems to cover only how to add an entry to grub when it already has a working system running on it.

https://blog.viktorpetersson.com/2014/07/29/how-to-boot-from-usb-with-grub2.html tells me to run the following from the grub shell:

```
grub> linux (hd1,msdos1)/install/vmlinuz root=/dev/sdb1
grub> initrd (hd1,msdos1)/install/initrd.gz
grub> boot
```

But the stick only contains /efi/boot/bootx64.efi and /efi/boot/grubx64.efi. I found this by setting `set root=(hd1,msdos2)` (which is the usb stick) and then tabbing through on `find /`. So my question is: how can I make grub boot from this USB stick?

PS: on this computer, booting to usb from the BIOS does not seem to work.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS. And once you start booting in one mode, you cannot change, or grub only can boot other systems installed in same boot mode. And is USB flash drive a full install or a live installer. Full install has files as links to specific kernel in / so your instructions above will boot install. But live installer does not. Grub in live installer is for UEFI boot, and live installer uses syslinux for BIOS boot. Some more info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Booting_USB_drives_with_grub2_and_iso_files_.27grub-n-iso.27

Comment: You can also see the methods described at the following links, [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb#Do_it_yourself](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb#Do_it_yourself) and [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS).

Comment: I have been testing the answer below for about a week without problem. If you want to boot Full install USB from the internal grub, I can edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Boot ISO File on USB from grub

You can boot an ISO on USB by using your desktop grub to loop mount it.
Add the following menuentry, (or similar), to /etc/grub.d/40_custom:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso" {
    set root=(hdx,1)
        loopback loop /Ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/Ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso splash --
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
    }
```

Were x is the USB drive number.

Then in Terminal run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

You can add a ext4 persistent partition labeled casper-rw if you want persistence, then add a space and the word "persistent" to grub.cfg after "splash --"

### Boot Full Install USB from Desktop grub

You can also boot a Full install USB using your desktop's grub.

Copy your preferred menuentry from your USB's grub.cfg to /etc/grub.d/40_custom on your internal drive.

Then in Terminal run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. Would this solution be possible at all if my existing installation is broken and does not boot from GRUB? Is there any way to do this from just the GRUB command line?

Comment: @Joeytje50 : You can edit grub.cfg directly adding the menu entry above. I'm not sure it will work any better than the USB grub, but it is easy to try.

Answer (score -1):

if you used balena Etcher to flash the iso image to your USB, look again using the Windowz disk tool.  While the first partition of the USB has those bootx64.efi files, nowhere will you find an .iso file.

Apparently the balena Etcher app has trouble with creating certain distros, like Kali.